# Summarizing data by according to value of different column (R)

Tags: r

I have data for seven variables (eg, DW_20) every minute for a month. I would like to know the average of each variable for each day (9/1/18, 9/2/18,etc). I am trying to use dplyr summarise but am only getting a returned error message. I think this must be easy but I cannot figure it out!

Original Data (first 7 rows)

```
   Date   DW_20  DW_24A  DW_25A DW_26A DW_27A   DW_28  DW_29
9/1/18 0:00  995.88 1110.62 1229.14  -0.09   4.50 1100.95 913.33
9/1/18 0:01 1002.43 1115.85 1231.59  -0.09   4.50 1107.63 909.06
9/1/18 0:02 1007.01 1123.39 1236.75  -0.09   4.51 1108.37 935.00
9/1/18 0:03 1007.17 1121.69 1234.58  -0.09   4.52 1105.64 901.35
9/1/18 0:04 1005.27 1122.86 1233.25  -0.09   4.53 1107.56 911.15
9/1/18 0:05 1001.37 1116.39 1229.89  -0.09   4.54 1103.66 937.93
9/1/18 0:06  997.42 1112.40 1229.71  -0.09   4.55 1102.46 920.39
```

Code that adds column for day of measurement

```
    #Load Data
data <- read.csv("Sep_2018_Well_Flows.csv", header=T)

#Create column of measurement day
data$Pump_Day <- format(as.Date(data$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%d")
y <- data$Pump_Day
data$Pump_Day <- as.factor(y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thank you for sharing an example of the original data. Could you please share the output of `dput(that_data)` so that we can see what data types are involved?  Also, could you show what error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

If it is to group by each 'day', then convert the 'Date' to `Date` class stripping the time part and use `summarise_all` to get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(Day = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%y")) %>%
    # or use `mdy` from `lubridate`
    # group_by(Day = mdy(Date)) %>%
    summarise_all(mean)
```